# counter inside enumerateObjectsUsingBlock

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need to iterate through an `NSArray` to calculate some metrics (total height). Here's my code:

```
__block CGFloat height = someInitialValue;

[messages enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (condition1)
        height += someValue;

    if (condition2)
        height += someValue;
}];
```

Each iteration starts with `height = someInitialValue`. But I want to continually increase `height`. Is it possible to calculate the total height with block-enumeration or do I have to use fast enumeration?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You're doing operations on `height` and it's marked with `__block` qualifier.

Comment: @MaciejOczko, yes, but at the beginning of every iteration `height` became `someInitialValue`.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin It shouldn't do. Do you have some code that you have removed here for your question that sets `height`?

Comment: @jackslash, sorry, you're right. I made a mistake while debugging. I'll delete my post.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin instead it would be better to leave it for others and mark an answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are increasing `height` in your code here. `height` is marked with a `__block` identifier which means it can be set from within a block.

the `NSUInteger idx` block parameter is a counter for the loop (in case you need that).

There seems to be no reason to use block enumeration in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'someValue' is zero and you see the initial value every iteration.